# Android drawable not showing up

Tags: android, xml, drawable, android-button

I am trying to make a very simple button in XML with a drawable. The problem is it does not show up at all.

Here is the drawable code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
        <padding android:left="2dp"
            android:top="2dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:bottom="2dp" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
    </shape>

</selector>
```

And here is the very simple test activity:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context="com.vroy.trapper.testactivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/simple_rect_btn"
        android:text="Test Button"
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Only the text in the button shows.

What very simple mistake am I making?

Comment: Please, post the activity.

Comment: @statosdotcom I did post the activity code.

Comment: I mean the java code

Comment: Besides that, try to use an ImageView instead, it can easily be configured to act as a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use tag item as the direct child of the selector tag

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
        <padding android:left="2dp"
            android:top="2dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:bottom="2dp" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"
```

android:background="@drawable/background_button"